# How to calculate 2-10keV Flux or Luminosity by Power Law from 0.2-12keV with known $\Gamma = 1.7$

Tags: observational-astronomy, raw-data, flux

I have $0.2-12$keV flux observations, distance observations and $\Gamma =1.7$. I want to apply power law to calculate 2-10keV flux. How can i do that?